# How do I use separate recaptcha keys for development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

It says in the docs they recommend to use separate keys for development and production I have my site keys stored in .env

Answer (score 2):

> I have my site keys stored in .env

[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) is only supposed to be used for development. It's a convenience for developers to be able to set environment variables. However, because it is a file on disk it loses the [security advantages and configuration convenience of environment variables](https://12factor.net/config). It should not be checked into version control, and it should not be deployed to production.

For production, put your secrets in environment variables. Most cloud production environments include convenient interfaces to set environment variables for your deployments.

Alternatively, put your secrets in [Rails encrypted credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security).

Comment: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#alternative-api-key-setup says I can add an initializer file config/initializers/recaptcha.rb Isn't there a set of keys for development that will always get you the view that says 'this is for development only' instead of not in the list of site keys?

Comment: @onedumbquestion That's just hard coding the keys into a file. You could add code for a different key per Rails.env, but that requires hard coding the development and production keys in the code. That's a security risk, don't do it. What is your issue with using environment variables?

Comment: I don't know how to use different environment variables for development and production I guess would wanna only use env variables in production and hard coded into a file in development but i don't know how, can you tell me ?

Comment: @onedumbquestion In production, use real environment variables. I can't tell you how to do this without knowing your production environment. For development, use dotenv. Put your key/value pairs in the .env file. Dotenv will take the values from the file and set them as environment variables. *Do not commit .env.* *Do not use the dotenv gem in production.*

Answer (score 0):

Just use different `.env` file on your server

Or create `.env.production` file. If you use dotenv gem, it has higher priority

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use

Of course both files must be git ignored

Or use rails credentials. In new rails (probably since 6.0) you can use different credentials in different environments

Comment: What keys to use for development?

Comment: For example `ENV['SITE_KEY']` and `ENV['SECRET_KEY']`

Comment: I added localhost on my google console and put logic in config/initializers/recaptcha.rb to test for environment Can I put logic in initializers, cause it's working on localhost now

Comment: Of course you can. Put these `ENV` or `Rails.credentials` there

Comment: mechnicov suggests using .env file How is that more secure than having the keys in another file?

Comment: My thought is to put the environment variables for the keys in nginx.conf for each site since they're different for each site and it's better than hard coding them into my sites? what makes credentials.yml more secure than another file like rechaptcha.rb?

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode keys in `recaptcha.rb`